# Curl with SSL failing to download with https (DigitalOcean Ubuntu Server 15.04)

Tags: openssl, curl, certificates

Received this error message:

```
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/share/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
```

...when trying to install a version of ruby through rbenv. The ca-certificates package is installed, running `sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh` changes nothing, `curl-config --ca` comes out with a blank line, and the CAfile mentioned in the error message doesn't exist (there isn't even a /usr/local/opt).

Any ideas what could have caused this and how to fix it?

Comment: Didn't you find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue with a Debian system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" the problem with:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/share/
sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/share/ca-bundle.crt
```

After this, curl works correctly, though I'm still unsure as to what caused the issue in the first place.